# the functor Ext repairs the inexactitude of Hom on the right

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

For a short exact sequence of R -modules: $ 0 \longrightarrow A \longrightarrow B \longrightarrow C \longrightarrow 0$. Prove that:

the following sequence is exact
$0 \rightarrow \mathrm{Hom} (C,G)\rightarrow \mathrm{Hom}  (B,G)\rightarrow \mathrm{Hom} (A,G) \overset{E^*}\longrightarrow \mathrm{Ext} (C,G) \rightarrow \mathrm{Ext}  (B,G) \rightarrow \mathrm{Ext} (A,G)$

with $ E^{*}:\mathrm{Hom} (A,G) \longrightarrow \mathrm{Ext}  (C,G)$ define:$E^{*} \alpha=\alpha E, $ for any $\alpha \in \mathrm{Hom} (A,G)$

I can't prove the exactness at $\mathrm{Ext} (B,G)$. Anyone could help me?

This is theorem 3.2 in Homology (Maclane)

Comment: What definition of Ext are you using?

Comment: In any case, this is somehwat long and is in fact written in tens of textbooks. I suggest you pick a gentler book which provides the details.

Comment: Could you suggest me some books about this? Mariano

Comment: Hilton-Stammbach, or Rotman are good candidates.